# Scripts not running in IFrame with IE - FF is ok

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a DNN website with an IFrame which points to another site.  This works fine in FireFox.

However, when testing with IE 10, the scripts inside the IFrame do not run.  If I test the site in IE outside of the IFrame, then the site runs fine.

I have tried compatibility mode, but the scripts still do not run.

Comment: IE 10 has a console  what does it say ?

Comment: It says: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Comment: The version of jscript is 1.10.2, by the way, as far as I can tell. But from other posts, the version is said to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an IE Security issue. Even through JavaScript was enabled for the main site, and the site that was in the IFrame, it was not good enough. Once I changed the "Internet" zone settings to allow JavaScript, it then worked.